# Prototypical alternative to Ext.define?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

Working a variety of JS ides, all of them get lost when defining custom objects using Ext.define.  All of them work fine when defining simple js objects via prototypes (function definition, and then prototype functions etc).  Is there an alternative to Ext.define that reuses and existing definition - something to decorate an existing object instead of define it?  I don't even mind if it doesn't pickup base class stuff, I just care about my definitions - also, I dont need dynamic loading so I no worries about load order etc.

For the record, I see that there is Ext.extend, but I would prefer to not explore this since it is deprecated.

Example below:

```
function Uploader() {
}

Uploader.prototype.execute = function(url) {
    //do stuff here.
}

Ext.???(Uploader, {
    initComponent: function() {
        // handle ext specific stuff
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after reading up on mixins I have a pattern that works.

Continue to use define to extend your ext object (for example a panel), and use the mixins array to add your prototypical object.  The defined class must have a different name than the prototype or else Ext wont create it as a definition.

Here is a code block demonstrating the technique:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    var Plain = function() {
    }

    Plain.prototype.message = "Hello prototype";

    Plain.prototype.say = function() {
        console.log(this.message);
    }

    Plain.prototype.hello = function() {
        console.log("hello guy!");
    }

    var p = new Plain();
    p.say();

    Ext.define("PlainPanel", {
        message: "Hello Ext",
        extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
        mixins: [Plain]
    });

    var p2 = new PlainPanel();
    p2.say();
    p2.hello();
    console.log(p2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how mixins are typically defined and used.

```
Ext.define('Plain', {
    message: 'Hello prototype',
    say: function () {
        console.log(this.message);
    },
    hello: function () {
        console.log('hello guy!');
    }
});

Ext.define('PlainPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    mixins: {
        plain: 'Plain'
    },
    message: 'Hello Ext'
});

Ext.onReady(function () {
    var p2 = Ext.create('PlainPanel');
    p2.say();  // Hello Ext
    p2.hello();  // hello guy!
    console.log(p2);
});
```

Instead of defining `mixins` as an array, define it as an object such that the property name becomes the internal reference to that mixin and the value is the class name of the mixin. This allows you to reference the mixin's methods even if the decorated class has its own methods with the same name.